# What is difference between spark-slave and spark-worker?

Tags: apache-spark, worker, slave

I knew that the slave was changed to worker in Spark configuration.

But When i download Spark-3.2.0, I saw both start-slave.sh and start-worker.sh exist under the 'sbin' folder.

Do both shells do the same thing?

Comment: the word slave is no longer used and master may well be on the way out as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These scripts are the same, `slave` has been renamed to `worker`

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32004

I assume that it remains old name for backward-compatibility purposes

compare:
3.2.0 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually
3.0.1 0 https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually